# Project structure with Vue JS 2.0 with Vue Router 2.0?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Vue just revamped its core and its primary router and since I'm just starting out using 2.0 and the Vue Router 2.0, there are a number of tutorials that reference older versions of either, and what I HAVE found is that the app structure varies wildly from boilerplate to boilerplate.

My question is this - what's the proper way to structure my Vue app while at the same time being able to leverage the new 2.0 router using nested navigation.

Thanks in advance.

Also, I've looked through the docs pretty closely and there seems like there are a ton of gaps - not sure if that's on purpose or the documentation just happens to be really thin.

Lastly, if it helps, I'm building a website that will have some application structure mixed in with it - making service calls to JSON data mostly and then populating tables with that JSON data.

Comment: Maybe you can look at this: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/tree/master/template

Comment: Thats the repo I was using but was having all kinds of issue getting the Vue Router 2.0 working with it.

Comment: have you tried vue-cli?

Comment: @flyingSmurfs I was under the impression that's what the mast template above was using. . . 

http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/

Comment: try this one https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/tree/master/template 
you need to get the latest vue-router with it

Comment: Okay - let me fire that one up and see if I can get it working. . .